# Manipulating the Terminal Using a Python Script

Tags: macos, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess

I have recently started using a program which has command line interfaces accessed through the Mac Terminal. 
I am trying to automate the process whereby a series of commands are passed through the terminal using Python.
So far I have found a way to open the Terminal using the subprocess.Popen command but how do I then "write" in the terminal once it's open ?
For example what I am looking to do is;
1. Open the Terminal App.
2. Select a directory in the App.
3. Run a command. In this instance the file I wish to run is called "RunUX" and what I want to type is "./RunUX ..." followed by command line arguments. 
I'm fairly new to Python and programming and appreciate all help !!
Thanks

Comment: if you want to control apps on your Mac then use applescript for that, it lets you open a terminal app, etc.

Comment: python would be a good choice if you want to do something remotely, e.g. deploy an app, or do some regular maintenance work on a server. The module you're looking for there is `pexpect`

Comment: Show us your work - we're not a code-request site. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments guys but I managed to figure it out. 
In the end I used a combination of subprocess.Popen() and os.chdir() and it seems to work using Jupyter Notebook.